# Unable to access websphere portlet wiring tool

Tags: java, portlet, websphere-portal, rad

I am very new to Websphere portal server. When I try to use the portlet wiring tool, it shows the following error message. I could not find any way to resolve this issue.

```
EJPAB0050E: The AdminNavHelper was not found on the request. This portlet requires that the AdminNavHelper tag be present in the theme in order to be displayed.
com.ibm.portal.WpsException: EJPAB0050E: The AdminNavHelper was not found on the request.  This portlet requires that the AdminNavHelper tag be present in the theme in order to be displayed.

    at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletWiring.portletWiring.doView(portletWiring.java:384)

    at org.apache.jetspeed.portlet.PortletAdapter.service(PortletAdapter.java:159)

    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.invoker.impl.PortletDelegateImpl._dispatch(PortletDelegateImpl.java:350)

    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.invoker.impl.PortletDelegateImpl.access$200(PortletDelegateImpl.java:70)

    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.invoker.impl.PortletDelegateImpl$Context.callPortlet(PortletDelegateImpl.java:553)

    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.cmpf.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:133)

    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.iwidget.filter.IWidgetLegacyPortletFilter.doFilter(IWidgetLegacyPortletFilter.java:51)

    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.cmpf.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:125)

    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.services.PortletFilterServiceImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterServiceImpl.java:368)EJPAB0050E: The AdminNavHelper was not found on the request. This portlet requires that the AdminNavHelper tag be present in the theme in order to be displayed.
com.ibm.portal.WpsException: EJPAB0050E: The AdminNavHelper was not found on the request.  This portlet requires that the AdminNavHelper tag be present in the theme in order to be displayed.

    at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletWiring.portletWiring.doView(portletWiring.java:384)

    at org.apache.jetspeed.portlet.PortletAdapter.service(PortletAdapter.java:159)

    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.invoker.impl.PortletDelegateImpl._dispatch(PortletDelegateImpl.java:350)

    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.invoker.impl.PortletDelegateImpl.access$200(PortletDelegateImpl.java:70)

    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.invoker.impl.PortletDelegateImpl$Context.callPortlet(PortletDelegateImpl.java:553)

    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.cmpf.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:133)

    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.iwidget.filter.IWidgetLegacyPortletFilter.doFilter(IWidgetLegacyPortletFilter.java:51)

    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.cmpf.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:125)

    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.services.PortletFilterServiceImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterServiceImpl.java:368)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom theme it might be that the AdminNavHelper tag is missing.  In the default theme it is in the Default.jsp file.

It looks like this: `<portal-internal:adminNavHelper/>`